# Monitor network traffic per client

Tags: mariadb

I'm investigating intermittent performance issues on a database running MariaDB 10.4 and I notice extraordinarily high network traffic.  `Bytes_sent` is about 20TB after running for 58 hours (379GB per hour).  There are only 8 clients, and typical traffic is expected to be about 2GB per hour.  Is there some way to monitor `bytes_sent` per client to help track down the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB has a [user statistics](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-statistics/) plugin that provides a breakdown per user.

It can be enabled dynamicly:

```
SET GLOBAL userstat=1;
```

And examined:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USER_STATISTICS\G
```

It seems like such a increase is potentially a brute force attempt or some abnormal use. I'd look at the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and see if the queries being run are extraordinary and/or you'll probably see there a client with more connections than expected.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Unfortunately I still haven't found the issue.  All the traffic is from root user, although it doesn't say which host.  I captured the general_log while traffic is climbing quickly, then ran each query manually (there were only a few dozen).  But this did not generate the high traffic.  Is it possible the general_log is missing some queries?

Comment: General log could be disabled and re-enabled globally by a root user. Maybe one of these would show up in the general log however. Try looking at the difference in numbers from `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` 10 minutes apart. Put the side by side in a spreadsheet and divide the number difference per second.  Look also for authentication brute force and errors (brute forcing SQL injection attempts).

Comment: Aha I found it! Nothing malicious, just sloppy code running SELECT more than it should. The reason I didn’t see the traffic before is I was running the queries from localhost so they did not show up in the statistics

Comment: Glad to hear it.